# Hyperref bookmarks for unnumbered sections

Tags: hyperref, titlesec, bookmarks

I'm using `titlesec` to format subsections so that they are not numbered (as opposed to using the usual starred variant `\subsection*`) and using `hyperref` to get bookmarks with section numbers in the resulting PDF file. The `bookmarksnumbered` option to `hyperref` does not know the `titlesec` formatting, so the bookmarks for subsections *are* coming out numbered, though…

**Question:** is there a way to get `titlesec` and `hyperref` to play nice to each other so that these numbers are omitted from the PDF bookmarks?

This little example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
        bookmarksnumbered,
        bookmarksdepth=2
        ]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsection}
        {\Large} 
        {} 
        {0pt} 
        {} 
        {} 

\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\end{document}
```

gets you this:

[image: Resulting TOC in the PDF]

Comment: My approach has generally been to use the starred form and then use hyperref's `pdfbookmark`.  Is there a particular reason you don't want the starred form?

Comment: @Teepeemm, mostly because I really prefer to be able to change the output without having to change the markup.

Answer (score 1):

your method to get unnumbered subsection is imho wrong: you still get numbers in the table of contents which looks simply odd:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
        bookmarksnumbered,
        bookmarksdepth=2
        ]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\subsection}
        {\Large}
        {}
        {0pt}
        {}
        {}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So why don't you simply change secnumdepth? Then everything will be numbered in the same way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
        bookmarksnumbered,
        bookmarksdepth=2
        ]{hyperref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, my tocdepth is such that subsections do not show up in the toc ;-)

Comment: your bookmark-tocdepth is not -- that's why you are asking the question don't you?